# How could I implement a digital signature in an application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, digital-signature

I'm developing a software in Ruby on Rails that saves information about documents that requires fisical signatures. The idea is do it all digital including the signature. How could I do that? Do I have to save a hash in the database?

EDIT:
Well, I mean [Digital Signature](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_signature)

Answer (score 1):

All depends on where you are and who your customers are. I'd recommend [this wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronic_signature#Enforceability_of_electronic_signatures) as a jumping off point. Once you get the legal aspects figured out we can help you out more with the implementation details.

PS. I'm assuming you're not talking about cryptographic [Digital Signatures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_signature). Let me know if I'm wrong.

Comment: Yes I do mean Digital Signature

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are in fact referring to [hash functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function), or message digest functions. Take a look at [Digest](https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://blogs.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/security/?p=683) library... And yes, you'll probably have to remember returned hash to the DB.